# Remap local paths for require() in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, require

In [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) I am able to remap paths using a [config file](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config), e.g.:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        foo: 'lib/foo/foo'
    }
})
```

I can then use foo like so:

```
require(['foo'], function(foo) {...})
```

In node.js I can similarly require local files, e.g:

```
var foo = require('../lib/foo/foo.js')
```

(In this example, `foo.js` is a file I have written that is not available via npm.)

Is it possible to remap `'foo'` to `'/lib/foo/foo.js'` relative to some base directory in node.js so I don't have to use relative paths?

Comment: That's what `node_modules` is for.

Comment: Forgive me, I'm very new to Node.  I thought `node_modules` was just for npm - are you saying that can put my own code in there without any risk of npm overwriting it?

Comment: No; I'm saying that you should put your code on npm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "remap" things in Node -- at least not natively, probably there are packages for this purpose.

However, you are able to put your code in the `node_modules` directory and require it.
But be sure to put your folder name in the `bundledDependencies` section of the `package.json` file. [See here](https://npmjs.org/doc/json.html#bundledDependencies) for more detailed info.

Comment: Thank you!  The bit about bundledDependencies is especially useful.